# When then in inner join condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.id where t2.col2 ='1'
SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.id where t2.col1 ='1'
```

can I merge both query in single query?
I tried using WHEN THEN!

Comment: put union between the two selects

Comment: see corresponding change in where clause column

Comment: `union` should work if the columns are the same in number and name.  Yours look like they _should_ work.  What result are you getting?

Comment: exactly what i want,not able to use order by now

Comment: so wrap the select ... union ... select in a select col1, col2 from ( ) order by whatever.  put the current statements between the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

how about `UNION`

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.id where t2.col2 ='1'
UNION 
SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.id where t2.col1 ='1'
```

Comment: what table do they belong: `col1,col2`?

Comment: friends relation ,and user details

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1, t2 
WHERE 
(t1.col1 = t2.id AND t2.col2 = '1')
OR
(t1.col2 = t2.id AND t2.col1 = '1')
```

is another way. But `UNION` should really work, too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
 SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.id where t2.col2 ='1'
 UNION
 SELECT col1,col2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.id where t2.col1 ='1'
     )
ORDER BY whatever
```